# Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response. in AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I keeps getting the error when doing PUT request to AWS apigateway with Fetch api in ReactJS. Pretty much sure I've enabled CORS in aws and depoyed it.

the fetch code looks like:

```
fetch(urlUpdate, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"           
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "Item": value;
        })
      });
```

GET and POST requests are all working, have't check DELETE yet.

Comment: Are you sure you've allowed that method server side using CORS? I'm removing the ReactJS tag, it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, I have clicked aws api gateway's enable CORS button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) clearly states that you need to manually add other methods unless you are limiting your resources to `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`:

> You must set up an OPTIONS method to handle preflight requests to support CORS. However, OPTIONS methods are optional if 1) an API resource exposes only the GET, HEAD or POST methods and 2) the request payload content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data or text/plain and 3) the request does not contain any custom headers. When possible, we recommend to use OPTIONS method to enable CORS in your API.

Scroll to the bottom of the docs page. You need to add

`method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods : "'*'"`